# MySQL query caching of inner query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a large query with many nested SELECT statements. A simplified version might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x IN(
   SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE x IN(
       SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE user_id = y
   )
)
```

Crucially, the innermost statement starts off by looking at the user_id and selecting a list of id numbers to use in the rest of the query.

The problem I'm having is that even if two users have the same data in tableC, the rest of the query doesn't seem to be cached.

For example if `SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE user_id = 1` returns (1,2,3,4,5)
and `SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE user_id = 2` also returns (1,2,3,4,5)

If I run the full query with user_id = 1 the execution time is about 0.007 seconds. If I re-run the query, I get a reduced execution time of 0.002. If I change the user_id to 2 and run the query, the execution time goes back to 0.007 for the first time the query is run. Is it possible for mySQL to cache the result of the individual parts of a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use mysql. So when you run query 'SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE user_id = 1' first time you get the result '1,2,3,4,5' and you query goes to query cache. Therefore the time execution after the second running is less than the first one. In this case your result is associated with your first query.
When you run the second query your server doesn't know anything about it. So it runs it and returns something(in your case results are identical). Next time when you run the second query you will get it from query cache and it will be significantly fast. Anyway the server will store two different records in query cache.

Comment: What about this part of the query `SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE x IN (..)`? The result is the same for when the user_id = 1 or 2. However, the execution time of the query suggests the cache isn't used

Comment: Query cache works in the following way: 1. Get your query and create hash. 2. Check maybe there is cached result. 3. If yes  then returns it if not saves into cache and returns it. In your case you will give two different hashes because queries are different and it doesn't matter what result they return

Comment: Thanks Andrej. I guess a solution would be to split the larger query into two smaller ones. That way I can save redoing the computationally expensive if possible